# $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is orientable, but $\mathbb{R}P^2$ is not

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, orientation

> Def: Let $U, V \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be open and $f: U \to V$ a
> homeomorphism. We say $f$ is orientation preserving if for all $x \in
>  U$ the composite $$ H_n(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \setminus 0)
>  \xrightarrow{tr} H_n(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \setminus x)
>  \xrightarrow{exc} H_n(U, U \setminus x) \xrightarrow{f_*}H_n(V,
>  V\setminus f(x)) \xrightarrow{exc} H_n(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n
>  \setminus f(x)) \xrightarrow{tr} H_n(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n
>  \setminus 0)$$ is the identity map. (Here tr denotes the map induced
> by translation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and exc denotes the excision
> isomorphism.)

> Lemma: A manifold $M$ is orientable iff it admits an atlas with transition maps orientation preserving homeomorphisms of open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

I am trying to show that $\mathbb{R}P^3$ is orientable **using this lemma**. So I constructed an atlas with four charts
$U_1 = \{  [1:y:z:w] \in \mathbb{R}P^3   \}  \xrightarrow{\phi_1} \mathbb{R}^3$ via $[1:y:z:w] \mapsto (y,z,w)$,

$U_2 = \{  [x:1:z:w] \in \mathbb{R}P^3   \} \xrightarrow{\phi_2} \mathbb{R}^3$ via $[x:1:z:w] \mapsto (x,z,w)$

and similarly for $U_3$ and $U_4$.

Now we would like the transition maps $\phi_i \phi_j^{-1}$ to be orientation preserving. This is where the problems start for me.

Let's check that $f=\phi_2 \phi_1^{-1}$ is orientation preserving. Let $(y,z,w) \in \mathbb{R}^3$ be arbitrary. Then $f(y, z, w)=(1/y, z/y, w/y)$.

However, the same proof should break down for $\mathbb{R}P^2$, but I can't see where this happens, so I know something is wrong with this "proof".

Comment: Mild confusion, but why are your transition maps going from $\mathbb{R}P^{3}$ to itself? transition maps are usually homeomorphisms from open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to open sets in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$

Comment: Thank you, I see this question doesn't make sense as written. I will edit.

Comment: I would suggest you work out the cases $n=1$ and $n=2$ explicitly, rather than jumping right to $n=3$. And use the correct transition maps :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to show that the maps $\phi_i \phi_j^{-1}$ are orientation preserving. For $i=2$,$j=1$ and your notation, this is:
$$(y,z,w) \mapsto (\frac{1}{y},\frac{z}{y},\frac{w}{y})$$
where we have to restrict to the set where $y\neq 0$. This changes the orientation of $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus \{ y=0\} $ (in particular, it is not the identity!).

One thing you could try to construct an atlas would be the following: Pick an atlas of orientation preserving charts of $S^3$ such that all domains of the charts are contained in a hemisphere. Since the antipodal map on $S^3$ is orientation-preserving, this will give you an atlas of charts such that on the intersection of two charts the transition diffeomorphisms are orientation-preserving.

Comment: You too have the transition mapping wrong. It should be $$(y,z,w)\mapsto \big(\frac1y,\frac zy,\frac wy\big),$$ shouldn't it?

Comment: Thanks both, the transition maps are now fine, but I guess my next question is why this is/isn't orientation preserving? If we start with a generator of $H_3(\mathbb{R}^3, \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus 0)$, which is a $3$-simplex, I can't see where this sends it to

Comment: Yes, you are right. I changed it. It does not make a difference for the rest of the argument.

Comment: Well, it does make a difference. The number of factors of $1/y$ in the Jacobian determinant will determine whether the manifold is orientable or not, once you correctly orient each of the Euclidean spaces. When $n$ is odd, you have an even number of $1/y$ factors; when $n$ is even you have an odd number, which will cause problems when $y$ changes sign.

Comment: @TedShifrin The number of factors of $1/y$ will determine whether the given transition functions preserve the orientation, not whether the manifold is orientable, right? This is not the case because - as you mentioned - the Jacobian determinant is $-1/y^4$, which is always negative.

Comment: @Christian: You have to *suitably* orient each of the $\Bbb R^n$'s to arrange that the Jacobian becomes positive. Obviously, we have to "cleverly" choose the ordering of the coordinates.  The question is whether we can do so to make them *all* compatible.

Comment: @TedShifrin I interpreted the question differently: Namely whether the transition functions in the question are orientation-preserving (where I assumed the standard orientation on $\mathbb{R}^3$. I do not say that what you say is not possible.

Comment: @DavidPopović I assume you do not know about the criterion with the Jacobian determinant? If not, note that the map $(x,y,z) \mapsto (x,xy,xz)$ is an orientation-preserving homeomorphism (on the set where $x\neq 0$). Postcomposing this yields again the map $(x,y,z)\mapsto (1/x,y,z)$. Can you see that this has the same orientation-behaviour as a reflection? (For me, it helps since the function $x\mapsto 1/x$ looks like a reflection.) Of course, reflections change the orientation.